# database app with one-to-many relationship has stray objects

Tags: ios, iphone, database, core-data, one-to-many

I have a database app of entityA <-->>entityB. To load data both entities have nstableviews. My problem is I've entered data for entityB's that apply to entityA's, but when I load the database into my iphone app there are a couple entityB's appearing without any related entityA's. I'm thinking entityB's have been added with no entityA's selected, and maybe this is why they're 'floating' in the iphone app.

Some questions:
Has anyone experienced this? 
Is there a way to prevent this in my drill-down database app?
Is there a way to code it so if any entityB's do not have a relationship to entityA's then delete it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answers to your questions.

> *1. Has anyone experienced this?*

Surely, many have experienced this. But I it should be unlikely if you are careful about the code you write.

> *2. Is there a way to prevent this in my drill-down database app?*

Of course. Simply make sure there is a parent entity and create one if there is not. If the A entity exists, it is just a one-liner.

```
newBEntity.a = existingAEntity;
```

> *3. Is there a way to code it so if any entityB's do not have a relationship to entityA's then delete it?*

Theoretically, yes, but it would be terrible code design. Just use the process in 2. above: create B and if there is no A entity, throw it away (e.g. by calling `rollback` on the managed object context). Or, as suggested, create a new A entity.

You could also (periodically or at app startup and shutdown) iterate through all B entities and delete the orphaned ones, but this would be very poor data design.

Comment: My model also has A<-->>B<<-->>C. It seems I can add to B's nstableview which means it isn't associated with an A. Would it be bad code to implement: - (void)prepareForDeletion {
    B *b = self.b;
    if (b.bToA.count == 0) { 
        [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:b];
    }
}

Comment: This code would be fine, though not desirable. The fact that there are other entities associated with a given entity is no good argument. As has been pointed out, deletion is best handled with the `cascade` rule inside the managed object model.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've specified inverses for your relationships, and proper delete rules.

Per Apple documentation, you should be supplying an inverse for each relationship, even if you only intend to use it in one direction. Failure to do this can cause model integrity failures like you're describing.